# How do I baste barbecue chicken while grilling?

Tags: chicken, barbecue, poultry, basting

I am going to barbecue 1/2 chicken on a gas grill. I want to use a water mixture with cider vinegar and salt, to baste while grilling. Can you give me any tips as I do this, like time and temperature?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with this basting? Are you trying to keep the chicken moist? To add salt and vinegar flavor to the outside?

Comment: Hi Gerry and welcome. I'm not 100 % sure what you are asking here. You want to know how hot the basting liquid should be or the grill itself? And you want to know when you have to baste or what did you mean with "time"?

Comment: Basting with such a liquid would actually be very unusual.  It sounds more like a Carolina style pulled pig sauce that is added after the pig is pulled, or even like a brine for before cooking.  It doesn't sound like something you would apply while grilling.

Answer (score 3):

Try a '[Beer Can Chicken](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000XE63M2)' stand. Use an empty (or not) beer (or soda) can to hold your basting liquid and properly place the chicken on the holder *(as pictured)* and put that on the grill.

[image]

As the chicken cooks your basting liquid will steam your chicken to a wonderful effect. IF you keep your lid down the steam will have the effect of continuously basting your bird.

Comment: The beer-can method is all psychological.  It's fun, but it really doesn't work the way people think it does. [Why Beer-Can Chicken Is Bad for Barbecue | Epicurious](https://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/beer-can-chicken-is-a-hoax-article)

Answer (score 2):

This basting method (cider vinegar and salt) was popular in the midsouth in the 60's. It does have a flavor similar to Carolina pork bbq sauce. Use a temperature of 400 to 450. Apply baste using cotton bbq mop (available on Amazon). It will usually take 30-45 minutes for split/half chicken. Tastes best if you baste each side twice.